# Why use an if statement with require?

Tags: php

While trying to understand code of a project I found on github, I noticed the following used in index.php when requiring another file:

```
If (!isset($_CONFIG)) {
    require 'config.php';
}
```

From what I see $_CONFIG only appears in that config.php at the very start where it is set to true.

Why would one take this approach and not just remove the if statement and use only:

```
require_once 'config.php';
```

Comment: Could be an oversight, or could be that they were allowing the user to populate $_CONFIG with some other data... and fallback to config.php to populate $_CONFIG with 'default' values.

Comment: Could you link to the code on github?

Comment: https://github.com/Thorium/webchess/blob/master/index.php